# Can't place extraPlugin to right place in toolbar of CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

After adding extra plugin in CKEditor: `config.extraPlugins = 'syntaxhighlight';` I can't put it on navigation bar at place I wanted.

```
    config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks' ] },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'spellchecker' },
];

config.extraPlugins = 'syntaxhighlight';
```

When I load CKEditor my syntax plugin is placed in `insert` group, and I don't know how to get it out of there or how to place it any where else.

**I'm using version 4.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to locate place where button is defined within **plugin.js** file, so in your case that will be:
**ckeditor/plugins/syntaxhighlight/plugin.js**

Usually button definitions are passed to *editor.ui.addX* method, i.e.

```
editor.ui.addButton( 'MyButton',
{
    label : 'My button label',
    toolbar : 'insert,100'
} );
```

You need to adjust `toolbar` property:
- string part `insert` tells which group will receive button.
- number `100` stands for its position. The lower number is, the higher priority your button will have.

You may update property into following value:

```
toolbar : 'insert,5'
```

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid code modifications, you can redefine entire toolbar, using the `toolbar` setting instead `toolbarGroups`. See the [toolbar configuration guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar).

Comment: Sadly Marek's suggestion did not work out :( I tried in different ways and all failed. And I guess I will need to use Reinmar suggestion as my solution. So Reinmar if you post an answer in a hour I will mark your answer as correct, if not then Marek's